# WinForms PropertyGrid behaving unexpectedly in WPF app

Tags: wpf, propertygrid

I'm using the WinForms `PropertyGrid` to edit object properties in a WPF app. However, the `PropertyGrid` isn't working as expected with certain property types. Specifically, objects exposing properties of type `Color` or `Brush` are displayed as text, `#FF000000`, for example, and the drop-down color selector list doesn't appear when a cell of that type is clicked in the `PropertyGrid`. It is my understanding that built-in editors exists for these types and I shouldn't have to do anything extra to get this to work (please correct me if I'm wrong).

For sake of brevity, I won't include a gazillion lines of code, but suffice to say that everything is pretty boilerplate. My implementation is culled straight from MSDN, SO or the myriad of WPF PropertyGrid examples floating around on the web. The `PropertyGrid` is wrapped in a `WindowsFormsHost` which goes into a `Window` that pops up whenever a user wants to edit an object. Something akin to this:

```html
`<Window>
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <PropertyGrid>
              ...
            </PropertyGrid>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
// BTW everything's implemented in code.
```

The actual objects are of course not passed to the `PropertyGrid` directly, but wrapped in custom `PropertyEditorObjects` which expose only those properties of interest in a predefined way, and at times these `PropertyEditorObjects` may implement an `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, especially when the objects being edited have child objects whose properties also need to be exposed to the `PropertyGrid` as nested properties. Generally:

```c#
public class PropertyEditorObject
{
    ...

    property bool SomeProperty { get; set; }
    property Size AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    property Brush YetAnotherProperty { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    property ContentProperties MoreProperties { get; }
};

public class ContentProperties : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    // Implements all the usual ICustomTypeDescriptor stuff.
}
// The PropertyGrid.SelectedObject is set to an instance of the PropertyEditorObject.
```

Everything works with the exception of what I mentioned at the start of this post: that certain property types (Colors, Fonts, etc.) are displayed as text only and the `PropertyGrid` doesn't use the proper Editor for that type.

The reason I'm asking fro help with this is because I'd like to use the built-in WinForms editors, such as the `ColorDialog`, `FontDialog`, etc. to edit these types without having to reinvent the wheel as my app is only in the demo stages. Any direction on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected.  The WinForms property grid knows nothing of WPF types like `Color`, `Brush`, or `FontFamily`, so it has no custom editors for them.  Have you tried one of the third-party WPF property grids?  I believe the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) has one.

Comment: I'd rather rather provide type converters and stick with the PropertyGrid as it's fairly robust and time-tested. I've perused the ExtendedWPFToolkit site but haven't downloaded anything yet because I thought I'd hunt around for a solution here first. Also, I'm not sure I want to be responsible for a `Community Version' of a third-party app, but I'll take a look. Thanx.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you want custom editors for WPF types in the WinForms property grid, you'll probably end up having to write them yourself anyway, which kind of throws the whole "time-tested" aspect out the window.

Comment: I downloaded, installed and tried using the `Extended WPF Toolkit` and its `PropertyGrid` as a solution to the aforementioned problem. Hate to say it, but I got exactly what I paid for. After struggling for hours just trying to install it (with or without NuGet), then fixing build errors, one-by-one, because there were missing project references, `#using` directives - most of which are poorly documented, if at all - redecorating my properties with still further undocumented attributes and the like - I did finally get it to build w/o errors and run ....

Comment: ... only to find out it throws an exception when the `SelectedObject` property is set to a derivative of `System.Windows.Shapes`, e.g. Ellipse. Yes kids: `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid m_PropertyGrid = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyGrid(); m_PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new Ellipse();` gives Unhandled exception of type System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ... Other UIElements seem to work. Now how lame is that? I will at least send a bug report as I couldn't find anything. I guess all those blurbs I read about there being no stable WPF property grid are true.

Comment: Actipro has a decent PropertyGrid implementation, but it's not free.  I'm not sure about any others.

Comment: I did submit a bug report to CodePlex re: EWT PropertyGrid crashes when SelectedObject set to Shape. They said it is an issue and will be fixed in v2.3. Until then ...

Comment: Here's CodePlex's response: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/21384. Thanx for the suggestions. I'm going to explore writing some converters for the WinForms grid as well.

Comment: Do you really need to work with `Shape` objects?  Might be easier just to write a custom UI element to render simple geometry, or to use some kind of proxy object.  WinForms interop comes with its own problems and was only meant to be a stopgap during the transition from WinForms to WPF.  Nobody should be building new apps with mixed WinForms/WPF content at this point.

Comment: Absolutely I need to support Shapes and anything deriving from UIElement. Among other things my app (actually a class library/dll) provides run-time `designer' services where clients can drop in visual elements and manipulate them to design `documents' - like in WinWord. Now imagine if WinWord claimed - well, you can use any content except the letter `a'. As far as your assertion that nobody develops mixed WinForms/WPF, I wholeheartedly disagree. Next time you're in VisualStudio, right-click something in the Solution Explorer, click `Properties', and voila - out pops the ole WF PropertyGrid.

Comment: There are numerous blurbs floating around discussing the issue that WPF has no built-in property grid, the third-party stuff is, well, unstable at best, and the WinForms Property grid remains a viable solution, e.g. http://blog.typps.com/2011/04/getting-most-out-of-winforms.html. BTW since I just started on SO, and am classified as 'irreputable' (ha-ha), I can't move this discussion to 'chat', so if someone could help w/ that as I don't want to clog this up w/ comments.

Comment: The property grid in Visual Studio was rewritten in WPF back in VS2010.  And the VS developers went to crazy lengths to make all that Win32/WinForms/WPF mixed content work well together, because they work together pretty terribly out of the box.  Lastly, I wasn't suggesting that you not allow manipulation of conceptual shapes, but rather that it might be easier to implement that kind of simple geometry yourself than to spend hours hacking away at property grids (if you can't use `Shape`, implement a custom alternative).

Comment: I do have a bunch of classes that implement custom shapes, as I intend to provide special "shape libraries", which of course would dispense with this whole issue as I can expose any properties from those I want. I'll look into provide some simple geometry objects, but then there is still the issue of "you can use any content, except ..."

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution: `Install Extended WPF Toolkit Plus`, use the `PropertyGrid Plus` (which has a `SelectedObject*s*` property) as the editor, wait for the 'fix' in v2.3 that will allegedly support more 'types' (Shapes, spinning squigglies with flames shooting out the sides, the letter 'a', etc.) and, in the meantime if a user attempts to edit an unsupported 'type', throw an exception stating `sorry, but you should really send us some money first.` That's all for now. More sarcasm available as soon as I invent it. Thanx to the commenters for their suggestions. Toodles.

Comment: OOps, `PropertyGrid Plus` requires you to send them money first. Grrrr.... I knew there'd be a catch!

Comment: Well, since my temporary solution wasn't without cost, I'm going to have to unleash my 'Final Solution' wherein I round up all the Delphi programmers, put them into special camps and ... (oh, that's another project, sorry) Anyway, I can opt to use the EWT PropertGrid with its limitations or the WinForms PropertyGrid and its shortcomings. If I go with the latter, I may wind up with another side project, the all-new and improved WPF PropertyGrid. Stay tuned.

Comment: Someone posted a Native WPF PropertyGrid on CodeProject, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-PropertyGrid, wherein they used the Windows Workflow Foundation's PropertyInspector, touting it as a 'full-fledged property grid'. Unfortunately, after preliminary testing, it functions no better than the Winforms PropertyGrid. Brushes, Pens, etc. still display as text and no editor is available. I'm sure custom editors/converters can be added, but that sorta puts me back at doing the same for the Winforms PropertyGrid, which I've already done for a few types. Works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Update on solutions:

1) Use the Winforms `PropertyGrid`, as stated in the original post, add `EditorAttributes` to properties that need them, e.g. Colors, Fonts, etc., and open the Winforms `ColorDialog`, `FontDialog`, etc., to edit them. Requires some type conversion but only a few lines of code. Not the best solution, but WORKS.

2) Use the `Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid`. Works, sorta, but with limitations. Doesn't support all types nor multiple-object selection, i.e. no `SelectedObjects` property. The first issue is to be fixed in v2.3 of the Toolkit. The second is sort of a showstopper without writing wrappers to facilitate the functionality.

3) Use the `Extended WPF Toolkit Plus`, `PropertyGrid Plus`. Allows for multiple-selection, but still suffers from limited type selection. Also, costs big dinero.

4) Use the `WWF PropertyInspector` as a WPF PropertyGrid. Looked good on paper, but wound up functioning no better than the WinForms `PropertyGrid`. Requires editors/converters.